# Каким образом несоблюдение принципа разделения интерфейсов связывает клиентские классы?

Tags: java, ооп, solid

Я не очень хорошо понимаю ISP. Опишу как я его понимаю.

```
public interface SenderAndSaver {
    void send();
    void save();
}

public class Sender1 implements SenderAndSaver {
    @Override
    public void send() {
        // делать что-то
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        // делать что-то
    }
}

public class Sender2 implements SenderAndSaver {
    @Override
    public void send() {
        // делать что-то
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        // делать что-то
    }
}

public class Saver1 implements SenderAndSaver {
    @Override
    public void send() {
        // делать что-то
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        // делать что-то
    }
}

public class Saver2 implements SenderAndSaver {
    @Override
    public void send() {
        // делать что-то
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        // делать что-то
    }
}
```

Есть "жирный" интерфейс. От него наследует 4 класса. Далее, клиентские классы пользуются ими так:

```
public class SenderClient {
    public void someMethod(SenderAndSaver sas) {
        sas.send();
    }
}

public class SaverClient {
    public void someMethod(SenderAndSaver sas) {
        sas.save();
    }
}
```

Одному из клиентов нужна только функция `send()`, а другому только функция `save()`. Считается, что если из-за `SenderClient` изменится метод `send()`, например, добавится параметр, то это повлияет и на `SaverClient`. Но каким образом? Весь смысл же в том что `SaverClient` не использует метод `send()`. Иначе бы и не был интерфейс жирным, если бы все клиенты пользовались всеми методами. Но если `SaverClient` не пользуется методом `send()`, как изменение `send()` может на него повлиять?

Comment: Ну так если вы изменили интерфейс, значит все клиенты интерфейса должны будут измениться (чтобы совпадала сигнатура методов). Но тогда придется менять классы, которым этот метод не нужен (что уже можно считать нарушением принципа одиночной ответственности). Почему бы не создать отдельно интерфейсы Sender и Saver и дополнительно SenderAndSaver, который наследуется от этих двух интерфейсов (надеюсь, в java это можно), тогда и проблем не будет.

Comment: Т.е. раз вы реализуете интерфейс, значит вы должны реализовать все методы этого интерфейса, поэтому при изменении интерфейса вам придется менять соответствующие методы, отсюда и *это повлияет и на SaverClient*

Comment: @ВОРОН, да конечно, так и надо было бы сделать. Моя проблема не в том что я не знаю как следовать этому принципу. А в том, что не понимаю, как не соблюдение этого принципа влияет на клиентов.

Comment: @ВОРОН, каким образом? Это повлияет на всех наследников интерфейса - это понятно. Но SaverClient вообще никак не изменится

Comment: я плохо знаком с java - разве после добавления параметра в метод интерфейса можно будет оставить старую сигнатуру метода в классе? в любом случае - добавить соответствующий метод вы будете должны (даже если и с другой сигнатурой), и проблема как раз в этом - вы должны писать код, который вашим классом никак не используется. Представьте, что у вас куча таких "жирных" интерфейсов и один из классов должен реализовать их несколько - в нем будет куча кода, который ему не нужен. Но раз он не нужен - то зачем его писать? Отсюда и принцип - используйте только то, что надо и на стопкой больше

Comment: вы читали [эту статью](http://blog.byndyu.ru/2009/11/blog-post_19.html), может так будет проще понять? Там и пример "влияния" есть: *Основная мысль в том, что теперь различные части системы зависят друг от друга, хоть и косвенно. Консольное приложение зависит от логики хранилища и наоборот.*

Comment: @ВОРОН, читал и перечитывал статью и все равно не понял. Я понимаю что изменять придется всех наследников и это плохо. Но причем тут SaverClient? В его коде ни разу не упоминалась функция send(). Как же изменения в send() могут повлиять на SaverClient?

Comment: ааа, я немного запутался в вашем коде )) теперь понял, на SaverClient это никак не влияет, влияет на то, что вы ему передаете. Раз у вас SaverClient использует только метод save, то логично, что ему можно было бы передать простой saver, который только этот метод и реализует. Но поскольку интерфейс жирный, то этот объект-параметр должен будет иметь пустой метод send. А вот здесь уже работает то, о чем я и писал выше. В итоге получается - ваш SaverClient может работать со многими клиентами, но вынужден работать только с теми, у кого дополнительно есть метод send

Comment: @ВОРОН, точно) теперь понятно, спасибо)

Comment: ну и, соответственно, выделив интерфейсы Sender, Saver и SenderAndSaver в вашем SaverClient можно было бы просто указать `someMethod(Saver sas)`, тогда класс работал бы и с Saver , и с SenderAndSaver, т.е. не пришлось бы лепить кучу лишнего кода, т.к. клиенты реализовывали бы только то, что необходимо клиентам, а не вашему SaverClient

Comment: Автор, если вам всё понятно стало, не могли бы вы сформулировать полный ответ для остального сообщества? Спасибо.

Comment: А заодно пометить его как верный (если стесняетесь набивать себе рейтинг, можете сделать ответ общим).

Answer (score 3):

В результате обсуждения я понял ответ на свой вопрос. Опишу как я это понял.

Возможно, в будущем кто-то создаст такой интерфейс:

```
public interface ISaver {

void save();

}
```

От него унаследуют конкретные Saver-ы. Их с радостью мог бы использовать SaverClient - они подходят для его нужд. Но он не может этого сделать, потому что завязался на интерфейс `SaverAndSender`, т.е. он завязан еще и на метод `send()`.